# Properly cast generics

Tags: java, generics

How can I cast `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` to `Class<T>`, where `<T extends Enum<T>>`? Specifically I need to pass an instance of `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` to the `Enum.valueOf()` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Here are the classes I have:

```
enum Foo1 implements Bar {
  VALUE1("A"), VALUE2("B");

  String me;

  Foo1(String me) { 
    this.me = me;
  }

  String getMe() {return me;}
}

enum Foo2 implements Bar {
  V1("A"), V2("B");

  String me;

  Foo2(String me) { 
    this.me = me;
  }

  String getMe() {return me;}
}

interface Bar {
  String getMe();
}

enum Z { 
  Z1(Foo1.class), Z2(Foo2.class);
  private final Class<? extends Enum<? extends Bar>> myEnum;
  Z(Class<? extends Enum<? extends Bar>> myEnum) {
     this.myEnum = myEnum;
  }

  Class<? extends Enum<? extends Bar>> getMyEnum() {
     return myEnum;
  }
}

class X {
   public getMe(Z z, String fooValue) {
       Class<? extends Enum<? extends Bar>> fooEnum = z.getMyEnum();
       // does not compile
       return ((Bar)Enum.valueOf(fooEnum, fooValue)).getMe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Casting is unsafe by nature. Can you show us what you are trying to do and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to cast to the raw type `Class`:

```
return ((Bar)Enum.valueOf((Class)fooEnum, fooValue)).getMe();
```

If you don't like casts you could wrap your enum classes in another class when you put them in Z to preserve more of their type relationship.

```
enum Z {
    Z1(new Holder<>(Foo1.class)), Z2(new Holder<>(Foo2.class));
    private final Holder<?> myEnum;

    Z(Holder<?> myEnum) {
        this.myEnum = myEnum;
    }
    Holder<?> getMyEnumHolder() {
        return myEnum;
    }

    static class Holder<T extends Enum<T> & Bar> {
        private final Class<T> myEnum;

        private Holder(Class<T> myEnum) {
            this.myEnum = myEnum;
        }

        Class<T> getMyEnum() {
            return myEnum;
        }
    }
}

class X {
    public static String getMe(Z z, String fooValue) {
        return Enum.valueOf(z.getMyEnumHolder().getMyEnum(), fooValue).getMe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

```
class X {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Enum<T> & Bar> String getMe(Z z, String fooValue) {
        Class<T> fooEnum = (Class<T>) z.getMyEnum();
        return Enum.valueOf(fooEnum, fooValue).getMe();
    }
}
```

Externally, the type parameter is useless. Internally, it lets us declare a type that is both a subtype of `Enum` and of `Bar`. The cast to `Bar` is also no longer necessary.

Comment: And due to special enum rules this is about as safe as unchecked gets.

Comment: @Radiodef I'd like to hear in what sense and why. There is no `Enum` type where the two `?` appearing in a declaration `Class<? extends Enum<? extends Bar>>` would be different. Enum are not a generic concept. There are no casts here that I can think of (give any inputs) that would cause this to fail.

Comment: That's what I mean. The cast should never fail.

Comment: @Radiodef Oh, haha. I read _this is about as unsafe_. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is impossible to express the type relationship that you need to, given Java's current generic grammar constructs. So you can do something unchecked, or, if all you need is to do something like

```
String str = someX.getMe(Z1, "VALUE1");
```

then you can ditch enum and declare `Z` as a regular class that takes a parameter. This way you retain a complete type argument and can use it later.

```
public final class Z<E extends Enum<E> & Bar> {
    public static final Z<Foo1> Z1 = new Z<>(Foo1.class);
    public static final Z<Foo2> Z2 = new Z<>(Foo2.class);

    private final Class<E> myEnumClass;

    private Z(Class<E> myEnumClass) {
        this.myEnumClass = myEnumClass;
    }

    public Class<E> getMyEnumClass() {
        return myEnumClass;
    }

    /*
     * recreate enum functionality if needed
     */
}

public <E extends Enum<E> & Bar> String getMe(Z<E> z, String fooValue) {
    Class<E> fooEnumClass = z.getMyEnumClass();
    return Enum.valueOf(fooEnumClass, fooValue).getMe();
}
```

Enum is not very flexible. There are things that it just can't do and it may not be appropriate.